# Help me solve several problems with Redshift on Lubuntu 21.04

Tags: lubuntu, redshift

I have multiple issues with Redshift.

The first issue has to do with two Redshift instances running simultaneously. There are five processes in GNOME System Monitor as seen in [this image](https://imgur.com/a/cjE7H40), but I think that there are two instances because I see two icons in the system tray as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/jqEneqF), and both act like two instances. E.g., if I place my `redshift.conf` file in `~/.config` then reboot, the two will fight each other, continuously changing from red to no red during the day.

However, if I install Redshift afresh, there's only one instance. The problem arises when I reboot.

The next issue has to do with my `redshift.conf` file.  I've set it up correctly, with the right lat and lon, both negative because I live in the Americas. But, the redness effect is applied during the day regardless. This happens with one Redshift instance. I've described above what happens with two.

And lastly, Redshift comes back after I close it, even with autostart disabled. E.g., if I click on "Quit," the redness effect goes away if any, the icon in the system tray disappears, then a new one comes up and so does the redness effect if applicable. This happens when there are two instances and when there's only one instance.

A few things worth noting are that I'm on Lubuntu 21.04 and I installed the status icon program to control Redshift and Redshift itself via Discover.

Also, here's the content of the `redshift.conf` file:

```
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=5800
temp-night=4800

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0
;brightness=0.9
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night since version 1.8.
;brightness-day=0.7
;brightness-night=0.4
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel individually)
gamma=0.9

;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'gnome-clock', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings
; e.g. 'redshift -l manual:help'
[manual]
lat=-35
lon=-55

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the second screen.
[randr]
screen=0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't added `redshift` (or `redshift-gtk` | `redshift-qt`) to an autostart have you?  as it has a 'autostart' feature, where if both are utilized, there will be two running (one you started; the one as consequence of telling redshift to autostart itself). As for lat/long, I didn't understand the +/- values so just used whatever I found worked for me (trial and error as details search engines provided didn't match they way redshift conf file wanted it)

Comment: Yes, I've added Redshift to an autostart and enabled the autostart feature. I'll test removing the first autostart, then I'll let you know of the outcome. @guiverc

Comment: Here's what I did: 1) uninstall both programs, 2) reboot, 3) install them again, 4) remove Redshift from applications startup, 5) open Redshift, 6) enable the autostart feature, and 7) reboot. All while having my `redshift.conf` file in `~/.config`. However, the outcome is nearly the same. The screen still continuously switches between red and no red during the day. This time, only one icon appears in the system tray. Also, instead of five processes running in the background, there are three. One of them is named "redshift-gtk" while the other two are named "redshift." @guiverc

Comment: I think that the status icon program has something to do with this because Redshift works perfectly if I have that program uninstalled. What are your thoughts? @guiverc

Comment: By status icon do you mean `redshift-gtk` (or redshift-qt) as I'm not sure what you mean. I like having a redshift icon on my panel so I can disable it when I need to concentrate and the redshift is working against that. If you start `redshift-qt` for example (or -gtk) it'll start `redshift` itself... so do not start a GUI tool (`redshift-gtk for example) and the backend `redshift` as that will result in two running (the GUI frontend will start it's own redshift backend).  I'd suggest checking https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html and what you have autostarting.

Comment: The status icon program I'm talking about is the GUI tool. In Discover, I see two things I can install. One of them is Redshift itself. It has the image of a package. The other thing I can install is the GUI tool. That one has the image of the icon. I'll do as you said regarding autostart and get back to you once I'm done testing. @guiverc

Comment: What was added to autostart in Session Settings was `redshift-gtk`, not `redshift`. However, the autostart was disabled, so I doubt it had anything to do with this. I think that what I install through Discover, `redshift` or `redshift-gtk` plus `redshift`, adds to a kind of invisible startup. If I install `redshift` afresh without `redshift-gtk`, remove it from autostart in Session Settings, then reboot, `redshift` autostarts regardless.  From there, if I add `redshift` to autostart in Session Settings, then reboot, the second instance shows up. @guiverc

Comment: Something similar happens with `redshift-gtk`. If I have it installed and added to autostart in Session Settings, then reboot, I get two `redshift-gtk` processes. @guiverc

Comment: I saw & I couldn't re-create your issues... then realized `redshift-qt` hadn't been packaged for our recent releases.. so was going to package it & upload to my own PPA, then potentially move to Lubuntu's (*that would require team consultation before I'd do that though*).. but my keys had expired.. and I've gotta fix that first.. I've not progressed there (*I have two different key issues; steps I only do once every 2-3 years so I never learn it properly*) & my progress stalled weeks ago now.. My only thoughts I've already added (ie. ensure you're not running it twice, autostart + self-start)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the follow up, even if you have nothing new to add. I've already tried what you suggest. No matter what I do, `redshift` will autostart even if it's not added in Session Settings. I'm dealing with other things, so I haven't looked into this any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04.

It seems that there is one instance started by systemd (which crashes and gets restarted several times) and one instance started via the app itself by enabling autostart (which creates an entry `~/.config/autostart/redshift-gtk.desktop`)

By removing `redshift-gtk.desktop` the flickering stopped, but redshift-gtk still crashed. I assume that it was either started to early or was missing a DISPLAY env-variable.

I had a hard time to remove redshift from systemd.
Disabling or masking the `redshift-gtk.service` did not work. Still crashed on startup.
I found that you have to disable the service with:

```
sudo systemctl --global disable redshift-gtk
sudo systemctl --global disable redshift
```

If you then enable the autostart via `~/.config/autostart/redshift-gtk.desktop` it works as expected.

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you so much :D